# How to upload a pdf file in JMeter along with Json body through API as a request without converting the pdf file into bytecode

Tags: pdf, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

can someone please help me to upload a pdf file along with JSON body as a request through API using JMeter?

```
JSON Body:- {  
                "name" :"xyz",
                "token" : "123OuvP4"

              }

Pdf file name - PT_001.pdf 

API URL - apiq-bbmma-stq.azure-api.net/DocMqmt/UploadDocument

Header Manager : - Content-Type:- multipart/related; Boundary:-"Aa0b12x"
```

please guide me on how to do that without converting the pdf file into bytecode

Answer (score 1):

I'm not getting your requirement. You should be sending the PDF file "as it is" in a separate "part" of the multipart request.

In case of [Multipart Content-Type](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.html) you need to send the message like:

```
--Aa0b12x
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{
  "name": "xyz",
  "token": "123OuvP4"
}
--Aa0b12x
Content-Type: application/pdf

your-pdf-file-content-here, it may be either "raw" or i.e. Base64-encoded
--Aa0b12x--
```

If you cannot build the request manually try just recording it using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html), just make sure to copy the PDF file to JMeter's "bin" folder before uploading, this way JMeter will capture the request and generate proper [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler and [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager). More information: [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter)